# Is it possible to install g++ on CentOS without root?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, centos, root

I've got a core i7 machine wtih CentOS 5.8 that I SSH into and use for running simulations. Unfortunately it only has gcc version 4.1.2. This seems to be producing vastly slower programs than what I get when compiling with optimizations on my slower laptop machine with Microsoft Visual Express c++ 2010. I've tried various g++ optimization flags but they aren't much help so I'm thinking i need to upgrade gcc.

I don't have root on the machine so it looks like I'd have to install it in my home directory. Is this feasible and if so are there any specific instructions needed to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use EasyBuild, which will allow you to very easily install a particular GCC version without requiring root, see http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild .

Disclaimer: I'm an EasyBuild developer.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was working with a severely crippled system but the developer here helped me get around this and now I have easybuild to install tons of stuff without issue. Awesome!

Comment: This doesn't answer question, it should shortly describe how install GCC using EasyBuild but instead there is only link.

Comment: After installing EasyBuild itself (see http://easybuild.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Installation.html), and configuring it (see http://easybuild.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#mandatory-configuration-settings), building and installing GCC is as simple as:

  eb GCC-4.9.3.eb

Comment: Agreed with @omikron I am sure easy build is great but you haven't answered the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GNU SRC..

After configuration, go to the gsrc directory and specify the following commands:

```
make -C gnu/gcc 
make -C gnu/gcc install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building from a source tarball, I believe you should be able to get by with `./configure --prefix=~/path/to/build/into` and then `make` and `make install`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a lot more complex than that. GCC depends on GMP, MPFR and recent versions also on MPC. So, you'll need to install these yourself as well.
The good news is, you can trick the GCC build system to take care of this itself, which is exactly what EasyBuild does. It gets a little tricky though, which is exactly why I recommend EasyBuild (we've put quite a bit of time in getting this right, now everyone can just use it).

Comment: When I build my own GCCs from Subversion for testing against Parrot, the --prefix is all I need, but that's because I've already gone through all those other installs.  Very cool that you've packaged it all up like that.

Comment: Is there a way to install GCC in some specific folder (such as my home directory) WITHOUT having to build GCC from source? I mean, is there a way to install it from RPM, while specifying a custom target dir, and WITHOUT root/admin rights?

Comment: I found this article which explains how to install an RPM package into another target dir (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rpm-relocatable-packages/), but unfortunately gcc-4.8.2-7.fc21.x86_64.rpm is NOT RELOCATABLE :(